# I am trying to test my code but my testing for set method is not working

Tags: c#

Class method:

```
    public decimal GetVehicleSalePrice()
    {
        return this.vehicleSalePrice;
    }

    public void SetVehicleSalePrice(decimal vehicleSalePrice)
    {
        this.vehicleSalePrice = vehicleSalePrice;
    }
```

Testing:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      SalesQuote quote = new SalesQuote(5000.00m, 500.75m, .3m, Accessories.LeatherInterior, ExteriorFinish.Custom);
TestGetVehicleSalesPrice(quote, 5000.00m);
    }

    private static void TestGetVehicleSalesPrice(SalesQuote quote, decimal expected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test 1");
        Console.WriteLine("Testing method GetVehicleSalesPrice()");
        Console.WriteLine("Expected: " + expected);
        Console.WriteLine("Actual: " + quote.GetVehicleSalePrice());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    //Testing method SetVehiclePrice()
    private static void TestSetVehiclePrice(SalesQuote quote, decimal expected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test 2");
        Console.WriteLine("Testing method SetVehicleSalesPrice(decimal)");
        Console.WriteLine("Expected: " + expected);
        Console.WriteLine("S"  SetVehicleSalePrice(1000.00m));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

My testing for the get method is working but set method testing not working properly. I am not sure, How can I test a set method, please help me out in this, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear how your code tests anything in any case.

Comment: "working but set method testing not working properly" what do you mean?

Comment: I am trying to print the result using that but it's giving me an error.

Comment: in your code are few errors which would cause the compiler to refuse to compile the code like: ```Console.WriteLine("S"  SetVehicleSalePrice(1000.00m));``` missing concatenation, and ```void``` return type

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the following after you set your sales price:

```
Console.WriteLine("Actual: " + quote.GetVehicleSalePrice());
```

For your purposes, you are printing expected, but not printing actual for comparison. However, this is not a very good test case to begin with. You should consider researching and implementing unit tests, instead.

Comment: It's working thanks for your help and unit testing is coming in upcoming lessons, so currently we are using this methods as per ins.

Answer (score 0):

`SetVehicleSalePrice` is a void method but you are expecting it to output the value as its setting the value. if this is what you intend to do, change the return type of the method to decimal and return the new value.

```
public decimal SetVehicleSalePrice(decimal vehicleSalePrice)
    {
        this.vehicleSalePrice = vehicleSalePrice;
        return this.vehicleSalePrice;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("S"  SetVehicleSalePrice(1000.00m));
```

Your above line of code must throw a compile error. Assuming you have SetVehicleSalePrice method in SalesQuote class, you can try below code.

```
quote.SetVehicleSalePrice(1000.00m);
Console.WriteLine("After calling set :" + quote.GetVehicleSalePrice());
```

Comment: It's working thanks for your help. Really helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear about that. Can you kindly mark this as answer so other users who're facing similar issue can find it useful too?